# Can I assign custom keyboard shortcuts for menu items in applications?

Tags: gnome, kde, gtk, shortcut-keys

OSX allows user to add custom keyboard shortcuts for menu items. For instance you can define a custom keyboard shortcut for "Copy" and it will work for every application that has a menu item called Copy.

Is there a way to do this for GTK and/or KDE applications?

Answer (score 2):

There is an obscure setting that is for this. XFCE has it in the GUI, but Gnome/Unity does not. The feature is an obscure one that's turned off by default, and perhaps because so few people use it, [it doesn't always work very well](https://www.google.com/search?q=can_change_accels).

But give it a try anyway. You'll need to install gconf-editor, if you haven't already:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

If you go into gconf-editor and do a search (ctrl+f) for "can_change_accels". In the dialog, make sure and check the "Search also in key names" checkbox. You should see a result with something like /desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels.

Check that to True.

[image: gconf editor - can_change_accels]

Once that's enabled, you can configure shortcuts by clicking on a menu and hovering your mouse over an item. When the menu item you want to bind a shortcut key to is hovered over, type the shortcut. It should appear immediately.

There are some caveats. One is, I'm not sure this works with Unity's global menu bar. Since I don't use Unity, I can't test and make sure. Another caveat is that non-native Gnome apps probably won't do this. So for example, if you're running a Java app, don't expect this to work.

Comment: It does not work with Unity, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/610234

Comment: Just remove the appmenu packages and it'll work with the rest of unity.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Shortcuts and Gestures > Standard Keyboard Shortcuts
Select the action, select custom and press the None button.
Then press the shortcut you want to have for that action.
I hope I have helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

To enable this temporarily for an application (to just change the setting), run it from terminal like this (this is for gedit, replace with the executable of your application):

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= gedit
```